# collectionView isSelected property gets invoked during scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

This problem appears only on iPhone 6 iOS 13 and is not reproduced on other devices which os is higher then 13. So the problem is when you start scrolling collection, the selected cell (it's decorated with the border line), the border line disappears when scrolling and specifically when you finger is not in the area of selected cell, when you hold your finger on selected cell, the problem doesn't appear. Maybe it os' peculiarity.  Any ideas how it can be fixed?

Comment: would be nice to provide a simple to reproduce example (removing all the unnecessary code) that way others might be able to test it

Comment: How are you setting the "border line" on your selected cell? I just did a quick test on both iOS 13.3 Simulator and iOS 13.3 device (iPhone 7) -- and I'm not seeing any problems.

Comment: @DonMag I've set it up in my custom cell class inside didSet block of cell isSelected property. I removed that logic and put it inside the method and invoke it in collection view didSelect/didDeselect methods, and now the problem disappeared.